# WooCommerce Shop Orders behaving differently than Customer Orders. Why?

Tags: woocommerce

I am investigating the difference in behaviour between Customer Orders (the normal way) and Shop Orders (WooCommerce -> Orders -> Add Order, the blue button on the top) which are created by the Shop Administrator for a Customer:

1.) Customer Order:
Customer puts something in cart, wants to pay with PayPal, and decides on the PayPal screen to cancel the order, clicks the link and gets back to the shop.
The order is still there, products still in cart.

2.) Shop Order:
Admin creates order, adds products and finishes the order. Customer receives mail with payment link, which takes him to the order. Wants to pay with PayPal, changes his mind on the PayPal Screen and clicks "Cancel Order and return to shop", same as in 1)
The order is being cancelled and all Products removed from the cart one by one.

I wish I could avoid this and keep the products in the cart...but I have no Idea where to start.

The link for creating a shop order is: wp-admin/post-new.php?post_type=shop_order, which suggests to me to look for something roughly like this:

```
if ($post_type=="shop_order" && $action=="cancel_order") {
    clear_cart();
    cancel_order();
}
```

and comment things out.
Where could this code be? Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

For customer orders it works because the payment was actually never completed, therefore the cart was never emptied and cart items are still there.

For admin orders, there was no customer cart to begin with, so the customer will end up with an empty cart (or cart in it's original state).

You can bypass this by adding all order items back to cart, e.g. using `woocommerce_cancelled_order` action, which gets fired right after order cancellation.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_cancelled_order', 'recover_cart_for_cancelled_orders', 20, 1 );
function recover_cart_for_cancelled_orders( $order_id ) {

    $order = wc_get_order($order_id);
    if( $order ) {

        // Empty the cart first
        WC()->cart->empty_cart();

        // Add each item from cancelled order back to cart
        $order_items = $order->get_items();
        foreach ($order_items as $order_item) {

            $product_id = $order_item->get_product_id();
            WC()->cart->add_to_cart($product_id, $order_item->get_quantity());
        }
    }
}
```

**Note**: Keep in mind this might cause unwanted results and bad user experience for some customers. For example if customer creates an order (unpaid yet), then decides to start a new cart, and then cancels the original unpaid order, he will lost his current cart and instead he will end up with the cart contents from the original order.

To avoid this, maybe you could wrap the code inside `recover_cart_for_specified_orders` function to a condition and only empty/recover the cart if it is empty:

```
if( WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count() == 0 ) {}
```

Comment: Wow, sounds good, will try. But will all the orders that were cancelled by purpose stay cancelled?

Comment: The code does nothing with the order status, so they status will be correct, only the cart gets always recovered after order cancellation. I am not sure whether `woocommerce_cancelled_order` is only being run when Customer cancels the order, or when Admin cancels the order from the dashboard as well. Feel free to test it out and add some conditions as you wish (e.g. `!is_admin()` to limit it to front-end cancellations only).

Comment: Limiting to Frontend is good, thanks.